# left join and return only the last record from right table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

and just not work is that i need bring the last row of the right table that i call second_table

```
table_one:
id
user_id

second_table
id
payment_instrument_id



select p_i.id, p_i.user_id,  a_r.id, a_r.table_one_id 
from table_one p_i
left join (
  select a_r.table_one_id, max(a_r.id) id
  from second_table a_r
  group by a_r.table_one_id
) lastSD on lastSD.table_one_id = p_i.id
left join second_table a_r on a_r.table_one_id = lastSD.table_one_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JOIN` condition for your join to `second_table` is incorrect; you need to join on both `payment_instrument_id` and `id` to get only the last row:

```
select p_i.id, p_i.user_id,  a_r.id, a_r.payment_instrument_id 
from payment_instruments p_i
left join (
  select a_r.payment_instrument_id, max(a_r.id) id
  from second_table a_r
  group by a_r.payment_instrument_id
) lastSD on lastSD.payment_instrument_id = p_i.id
left join second_table a_r on a_r.payment_instrument_id = lastSD.payment_instrument_id and a_r.id = lastSD.id  
where p_i.user_id = 1030
```

Output (for a truncated sample of your data):

```
id      user_id     id  payment_instrument_id
803     1030        86  803
958     1030
```

Note you can simplify your code with a CTE using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH a_r AS (
  SELECT id,
         payment_instrument_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY payment_instrument_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM second_table
)
SELECT p_i.id, p_i.user_id, a_r.id, a_r.payment_instrument_id 
FROM payment_instruments p_i
LEFT JOIN a_r ON a_r.payment_instrument_id = p_i.id AND a_r.rn = 1
```

The output is the same as the first query.

Demo (of both queries) [on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c34f9d777254dd8dc5db3ba266d77b3)

Comment: yes perfect, thanks for your help, works as expected

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ Please see my edit, I've added a simpler query that does the same thing